# Problem with instances

Tags: sharepoint-online, pwa

I created a Project Web App site with Office 365.
I created it with the name *sharepoint.com/sites/ppm* because */pwa* was in use.

But the message appears

“No Project web app instances found. Create at least one PWA instance before accessing this page”

Anyone knows how i can fix this?

Comment: Have you gone into the site settings and ensured that the Project Web App features are actually activated?

Comment: Yes, all project web app features are activated
But "PWA Settings" Link is not avaliable